# Getting error 400 on valid link with $http.get

Tags: angular, search, odata

I'm trying to set up custom queries for an ODATA-source (Northwind) - I'm getting error 400 when GETting the URL - if I go directly to the URL in the browser, however, I get the corresponding results. Is there something else that should be specified in the function?

```
app.directive('search', function () {
return function ($scope, element) {
    element.bind("keyup", function (event) {
      let val = element.val();
      if(val.length > 2) {
        $scope.search(val);
      }
    });
};
});

app.controller('searchEmployees', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.search = function(val) {
    console.log(val);
        $http.get(BASE_URL+"Employees?$filter=substringof("+val+", FirstName) eq true")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.rawData = response.data;
    })
}});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="searchEmployees">
  <input type="text" search/>
</div>
```

If I try to search for f.ex 'Nan', as there is an Employee named Nancy, it works using the direct URL (http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$filter=substringof%28%27Nan%27,%20FirstName%29%20eq%20true), but not with my code.

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the URL into the app? If that still doesn't work then you can eliminate your URL building code as the problem.

Comment: Tried it now - result is the same unfortunately. :/

Comment: Have you tried a simple URL like www.google

Comment: Have you tried a simple URL like www.google.com?

Comment: It works if I drop the filter, but that would kind of defeat the point of the search box in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use encodeURI and backslash, to allow for ':

```
query = encodeURI("Products?$filter=contains(ProductName,\'"+val+"\')");
query = BASE_URL+query;
```